# Why is this logical statement not working?

Tags: r

Why doesn't the logical statement show TRUE?

```
> pfv0$x[480]
[1] -2
> pfv0$x[480] == -2
[1] FALSE
> is.numeric(pfv0$x[480])
[1] TRUE
```

I am fairly new to R and I feel like I am missing something easy here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to tell us what `pfv0` is. How was it created? What is x?

Comment: can you `str(pfv0)`?

Comment: This is almost certainly R FAQ 7.31, http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_82.html ... `x <- -2.000000001; print(x); x==2`

Comment: @HubertL
`> str(pfv0)
    'data.frame': 1000 obs. of  2 variables:
     $ x  : num  -49.9 -49.8 -49.7 -49.6 -49.5 -49.4 -49.3 -49.2 -49.1 -49 ...
     $ pfv: num  -0.0097 -0.00968 -0.00939 -0.00979 -0.01039 ...`

x is created by: `x <- seq(-49.9,50.0, by=0.1)` then put into a dataframe with pfv.